# Can't change the line-highlight color

Tags: themes, highlighting

I try to set a new hex-color to highlight the current line in the distinguished theme, but this can have no effects. I put this in init.el:

```
;;highlight current LINE
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
(set-face-background 'hl-line "#47310D")
(set-face-foreground 'highlight nil)
```

How can i change the color of the current line?

Comment: Are you place this after loading theme?

Comment: Sometimes getting these customizations applied at the correct time is tricky. Maybe it will be easier to use `M-x customize-group hl-line` than to do this in your init.el?

Comment: @KonstantinMorenko No its placed before `(load-theme 'distinguished t)`

Comment: So, `load-theme` could change value of this variable.  Try to place setting face after `load-theme`.

Comment: @KonstantinMorenko Perfect, this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put your code before `load-theme`, loading theme could change value of this variable.  Put your code after `load-theme` in your `init.el`.